# Nginx proxy configuration in front of Restheart

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker-swarm, restheart

I am running nginx as a front end reverse-proxy, in a docker (swarm, single node) container, in front of a Restheart application, delivering restheart REST services.

I am using the latest docker image for ngninx on Alpine.
The configuration file is attached below.

As a backend, I am using a standard mvn build uberJar of Restheart, where mostly only the root for REST ressources access has been moved to /api instead of /. This works perfectly when accessed directly.

When I test the upstream server ( Restheart ) on  (open for debugging) 8080 port directly, all REST apis work as expected.

I use httpie to do the testing.

When I go through nginx, on port 8081, with the same requests, the /api/... and /_logic paths/... are captured and work as expected.

For a reason I cannot understand, the /_authtokens/... and /browser/ paths are not passed to the upstream Restheart server, but end-up being caught by the first block, trying to locate a file with that name in the local filesystem, at /usr/share/nginx/html/...

What is really bothering me is that I do not see why it works perfectly on the first two paths and not on the other two ?!

Any hints or indications on where to look/search for would be greatly appreciated ? (already googled and scrateched my hairs for a few days now ... ;-)

### Xavier

```
# Configuration file for the nginx front-end container.

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}




http {

    sendfile        off;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # default_type  application/json;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  stdout  main;
    error_log stderr debug;


    upstream docker-restheart {
        server   myrestheart:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 8081 ;   
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_pass_request_body         on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect     default;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;  



        # Default will serve the index as a test.
        # This is also where non allocated locations will end up,
        # because it is the first block ..
        location / {            
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;           
            }


        # Restheart api - ok
        location /api/  {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-restheart;            
            }

        # Restheart _logic - ok
        location /_logic/  {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-restheart;
            }

        # Restheart _authtokens - does not work ?
       location /_authtokens/  {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-restheart;
            }

        # Restheart browser - does not work ?
       location /browser/  {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-restheart;
            }



        # Restheart _authtokens - does not work ?  
        # Restheart browser - does not work ?
        # In both cases, no transfer to upstream happening, 
        # but instead, caught by the first block ...


    }
}
```

---

```
# This compose file defines the docker stack for swarm deployement
#

version: "3"

networks:
  myoverlay:
    driver: overlay

volumes:
    dbdata:

services:
  mymongo:
    image: "mvertes/alpine-mongo:latest"
    command: ["mongod","--quiet"]
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db/
    networks:
      - myoverlay

  myrestheart:
    image: openjdk:8-jre-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./target/MyRestheart-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/myjar.jar:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: ["java","-Dmongo=mongodb://mymongo:27017", "-jar", "/myjar.jar"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - myoverlay

  mynginx:
    image: nginx:alpine    
    ports:
      - 8081:8081    
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/nginx.conf
    command: ["nginx", "-g","daemon off;","-c","/nginx.conf"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - myoverlay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have experienced similar problems with Nginx configurations in the past. In our case we moved to the regex syntax for locations, and it works. Something like:

```
location ~ /(api|browser|_logic|ping|_authtokens) {
    proxy_pass http://docker-restheart;
}
```

Ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: Thanks @mturatti. You (indirectly)  helped me find the answer. Not so much regex or not regex, but the factoring of the various proxy_xxx directives outside of the location was an issue. I moved it inside the location blocks, duplicated, and it now  works fine. No idea why factoring worked with /api and /_logic and not /browser nor /_authtokens ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove or move to the end the `location /` entry in nginx conf file.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. No change if I move location. I don't want to remove, because ultimately, I want to serve static content from nginx at the root without going through restheart/undertow ...